# How to test angular $destroy event on a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

The directive (isolated scope, transcluded, replaced) inserts a mask into the `<body>`.

```
var mask = angular.element('<div id="mask"></div>');

$document.find('body').append(mask);

scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    mask.remove();
});
```

I am trying to test this case with a simple broadcast on the scope:

```
var $document, scope, element, rootScope;

beforeEach(inject(function($compile, _$document_, $rootScope, $injector) {
    rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    scope = $rootScope;
    $document = _$document_;
    mask = $document.find('#mask');
    element = $compile(angular.element('<overlay id="derp"></overlay>'))(scope);
}));

it('should remove mask when casting the $destory event', function (done) {
    scope.$broadcast('$destroy');
    scope.$digest();
    expect($document.find('#mask').length).toBe(0);
});
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: can you show the directive and the entire spec?

Comment: produces the same result.

Answer (score 6):

The mistake was: the directive creates the `<div id="mask"></div>` multiple for mulitple overlays. So angular seems to have problems when adding multiple `<div>`'s with the same ID to the DOM. After fixing this, all worked as expected.

```
it('should remove mask when $destoryed', function () {
    scope.$destroy();
    expect($document.find('#mask').length).toBe(0);
});
```

Comment: It was impossible to detect it without seeing the directive itself. next time you post a question about directive tests be sure to post more of the directive code.

Comment: You can omit `scope.$apply();`